Configure Typescript package to be exported with two version
I am working on a TS package which includes common data models and service which are used in different (small and side) projects. I publish this pack on a private Gitlab package registry, so I can use it on Google Cloud Functions.
I want to start working on a new version (v2) of the data models that are already implemented, and I want to be able to use both versions on my projects, specially critical during the migration.
I should I configure my project exports and modules such that I can access the two versions using "subpath", i.e. import them as @my-company/my-package/v1 and @my-company/my-package/v2
As an example, my current directories structure is:
package.json
tsconfig.json
tsconfig-cjs.json
index.ts
/lib
  /models
    my-first-model.ts
    ...
/dis
  /cjs
  ...
  /esm
  ...

And I would like to migrate to:
package.json
tsconfig.json
tsconfig-cjs.json
index.ts
/lib
  /v1
    /models
      my-first-model.ts
      ...
  /v2
    /models
      my-first-model.ts
      ...
/dis
  /cjs
  ...
  /esm
  ...

What I would like to achieve is to be able to import it on another project list this:
File file1.ts in @my-company/my-other-project
import * from "@my-company/my-package/v1";
...

function myFunction(myParamV1: ModelFromMyPackage) {
...

File file2.ts in @my-company/my-other-project
import * from "@my-company/my-package/v2";
...

function anotherFunction(myParamV2: ModelFromMyPackage) {
...


A package registry may not support the structure you are proposing. Normally, it appears like this, @my-company/my-package@v1 and @my-company/my-package@v2. They belong to the same registry endpoint, so technically, one version must overwrite the other when you download/install it locally. If you would like to do so, you possibly need to have unique names for each.

Is it possible to just refer to a subpath of the package when importing/exporting it? In my case /v1 and /v2 have a meaning, but they could just be /models and /services and my question would be if I could import them as @my-company/my-package/models or @my-company/my-package/services in a file on another project just as I would do if they where local files that I would refer using their relative paths

You can do it with exports field of package.json:

You can migrate to lib/v1, lib/v2, as you mentioned
Then set up your build scripts to compile each version into separate directories within the dist
And add exports field to package.json, like:

"exports": {
    "./v1": {
      "require": "./dist/cjs/v1/index.js",
      "import": "./dist/esm/v1/index.js"
    },
    "./v2": {
      "require": "./dist/cjs/v2/index.js",
      "import": "./dist/esm/v2/index.js"
    },
    "./v1/*": {
      "require": "./dist/cjs/v1/*",
      "import": "./dist/esm/v1/*"
    },
    "./v2/*": {
      "require": "./dist/cjs/v2/*",
      "import": "./dist/esm/v2/*"
    }
}

main, module, types fields can default to the v1 path to maintain backward compatibility:
"main": "./dist/cjs/v1/index.js",
"module": "./dist/esm/v1/index.js",
"types": "./dist/esm/v1/index.d.ts"

And then you'll be able to import different versions using subpaths, as you intended.
